# Website doesn't seem to mail?

Tags: php, email, ubuntu

for the first time ever i'm using a VPS for my hosting i have Apache2, LAMP on Ubuntu 12.04 i have installed a website and it's not sending mail via my contacts page or the registration verification emails etc...? Do i need to set up some kind of outgoing mail server ? like this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-the-send-only-mail-server-exim-on-ubuntu-12-04 and if so will it work automaticly or will the sending script need to be reconfigured ?

Any help, links or info would be great.. i feel like this could be in the linux section on stackoverflow but i don't think ill get a answer there and it may require editing PHP so I've stuck it here. thanks for your time!

Email Contact form...

```
<?php
    if($_POST['submit']){
        $emailsend=get_value("siteemail");
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $website=$_POST['website'];
        $msg=$_POST['msg'];
        if(strlen($name) > 3 && strlen($msg) > 10 && is_valid_email($email)){
            $subiect="Contact support - Paid4Upload";
            $mesaj="Nume: $name \n Email: $email \n Website: $website \n Message: $msg ";
            $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"."\r\n";
            $headers .= "From: $email"."\r\n";
            mail($emailsend, $subiect, $mesaj, $headers);
            echo "<div class=\"alert alert-success\">Email sent!</div>";
        }else{
            echo "<div class=\"alert alert-error\">Please complet all data</div>";
        }
    }
?>
    <form action="" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Full Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="text" placeholder="" name="name" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="text" placeholder="" name="email" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Website</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="text" placeholder="http://" name="website" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Message</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <textarea cols="30" rows="5" placeholder="" name="msg" class="form-control"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="submit" value="Send Message" name="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: I think you will get an error on $emailsend=get_value("siteemail"); as this is not a function in php.

Comment: I think that's grabbing the site's set email from the admin panel ?

Comment: did you try 'echo $emailsend'? if yes, did you actually see an email id being echo'd?

Comment: <?php echo $emailsend; ?> didn't showing anything? i then set it to $emailsend="workingemailaddress@gmail.com"; and then tried to send but nothing?